If I wanted to build a space-faring probe),could it absorb the radiation in space and used it as fuel?
If I wanted to build a space-faring probe (no humans on board), would it be possible to build the structure and covering of the ship so that it absorbed the radiation in space and used it as fuel? I am thinking that it would be built on a moon or space-station and launched to make a long trip (50-100s of years) and collect data and bring it back. The idea being that 100s would be built and launched on a yearly schedule. Some would have 10 year missions and some would have 200+ year missions. No communication would reduce the weight, cost and complexity. By using numbers, if each were low complexity, we would ensure that even if we lost a few, we would still get large returns.
A few years after initiation, we would start getting the probes back.

People have made the point that "getting the probes back" is terribly complex, but a point that I feel requires stating clearly: it's much, much more complex for a probe to come back than for it to have communications equipment on board.  So having comms on board is a savings, not a burden.

yes we do it all the time, its called a solar panel.

@John - as Starfish Prime points out, using a solar panel nets you energy, which is neither fuel nor reaction mass.

@jdunlop its fuel in a ion drove just not reaction mass.

Power is not fuel and though it may provide energy that can be applied to reaction mass it is worthless for propulsion without any reaction mass to use it on.

As an explainer for why coming back is hard, I'd recommend https://what-if.xkcd.com/38/. Specifically this image.

Thanks for all the comments and information. That's what is great about this SO community, you can ask very vague questions and get back useful information and ideas.

The issue here is exactly what this "radiation in space" actually is. Around stars, you get a lot of starlight (which will include UV and x-rays and things) and stellar winds (which include all sorts of fast particles, including alpha particles and protons). Galactic cosmic rays are fast particles originating from outside the local stellar system, but whilst there are enough of these to be dangerous (to meat or electronic) they don't actually provide much mass or energy so they're not really useful to harvest as such.
Starlight you can obviously harvest via photovoltaic panels. Solar wind is more awkward. But that's power, which isn't the same as fuel, which in turn isn't necessarily the same as reaction mass. A rocket engine of the sort you might use for travel into interstellar space generally requires power and reaction mass... Dawn used solar power to operate an ion drive that used onboard xenon as reaction mass, but obviously solar power doesn't work that well the further you get from the sun which is why New Horizons and the Voyager probes, etc, use RTGs.
You can use stellar wind and light directly for propulsion with lightsails or magnetic sails. As with solar panels, these work best when you're close to a star and effectiveness drops off the further you get away, but they're useful for providing an early boost. Once you've reached the local astropause your sails won't be much use until you either reach a destination star, or someone shines a laser or particle beam on you (which is a different subject altogether).
There was a bright idea known as the Bussard Ramjet (named after its inventor) which was a fusion rocket that harvested gas and dust particles from the interstellar medium, fed them into a fusion reactor and used the reaction products to accelerate (thus using interstellar hydrogen as both a fuel to provide power and reaction mass). Unfortunately this ran into a whole load of seemingly insurmountable technical issues that meant that it couldn't really be any better than a regular fusion rocket would be, and it would certainly be a lot more complex.
There's nothing else out there to harvest unless you're going to start trying for zero-point energy, which seems dubious but has not yet been conclusively demonstrated to be impossible. If such a thing could be done, you'd have no problem running pretty much anything you'd like, probe and engine-wise, but it seems unlikely to ever be practical.

A few years after initiation, we would start getting the probes back.

Cheap probes don't come back, because that needs four times the delta-V (get up to cruising speed, then brake to a halt, then back up to speed again for the return flight, then brake to a halt for recovery) which is a) inconvenient to arrange and b) a lot slower than just breezing past the target at speed.
Even probes that stop for a good look around will do better beaming their findings back, perhaps by a communications laser, because it'll be an awful lot faster than flying back... probably hundreds of times faster, with realistic journey times.

Something I've wondered was whether it's possible in a hypothetical sense to leverage the blue-shifted CMB at super high speeds. Usually when you have a huge imbalance like that it's possible to extract energy, but I think the usefulness of such energy is iffy seeing as how the source lies dead ahead and opposes your direction of travel. Relativity does this weird thing though called aberration, and at certain speeds some stars that are still behind you become blue-shifted. Just an idle thought.

@BMF I think its one of those things where it probably does work OK, but is largely pointless by the time you're able to use it. Like sticking a little wind turbine on an SR-71... sure, you could, but in order to get that thing up to speed you must have already used some monstrously powerful propulsion system whose output so utterly dwarfs the power you get back that you may as well have used that technology instead.

@BMF and now I think of it, some ideas of interstellar propulsion certainly leverage the relative speed of particles on front of the spacecraft, because they have enough energy to fuse with a suitable fuel pellet without needing any extra encouragement, and the fusion yield can exceed the kinetic energy of the particle. You might be able to do the same trick with blueshifted photons, inducing photofission or photodisintegration. your fuel mass would obviously be limited, but you could use stable heavy elements, unlike other nuclear power designs...

Probably not
The majority of radiation in space isn't "radiation" as we think about it like neutron, alpha, beta, or gamma radiation that it might be possible to use for energy. Much of the cosmic microwave background radiation (which is what I think your probe might want to feed on, given that it's pretty much isotropically distributed throughout the Universe as far as we can tell) is in the 70-217 GHz range. Compare to microwaves, which are good at heating up water and the like and have frequencies aroudn 2.5 GHz.
This means that the CMBR actually has more energy than microwave radiation that we produce on the regular, but the energy density is much lower - around a quarter of an electronvolt per cubic centimeter. The temperature of the radiation is in turn only a few Kelvins, so without being able to magically  supercool your ship to near absolute zero without consuming too much energy, you'll be losing temperature in interactions with cosmic radiation particles rather than gaining it because the temperature gradient will favor the flow of energy from the high-temp system (your ship) to the low-temp system (the surrounding space).
But that's not fun!
Yeah, you're right. Powering probes far from stars for a very long time is a difficult process! Conveniently, if you're willing to handwave something that can act as a virtually-unlimited power source for a very long time, most of the other problems solve themselves (when I write SF, I usually just introduce cold fusion; then, torchships and unlimited power and all that come naturally). If you want to have the ships be able to eat radiation, then give them all "resonant-scattering cooling systems" that allow them to dump almost all of their thermal energy into their engines with high efficiency, so that after a few minutes of operation the ship has cooled to near absolute zero. This means that the temperature gradient will favor energy flowing into your ship, at which point the resonant-scattering cooling can use the heat to generate electricity to power a hyper-efficient ion engine or photon rocket.
Don't worry, you won't run out of energy. A quarter of an electronvolt per cubic centimeter sounds tiny to anyone who knows what an electronvolt is, but consider that that density is roughly uniform across the entire universe. The universe has a volume of about $4\times10^{86}$ cubic centimeters, so there's then roughly $10^{86}\text{ eV}\approx1.6\times10^{67}\text{ J}$ of energy to work with. That's actually not an unreasonable estimate for the mass-energy of the universe itself; you will be able to launch a hundred million new probes every second as fast as you want forever without exhausting this energy supply.
As for what this engine will look like, it won't be powerful. At its highest efficiency, you're running a photon rocket that uses the mass-energy of a laser beam as propellant, and at its highest thrust, you're running an ion engine with specific impulse in the millions of seconds that uses the microwatts of electricity extracted from the milliwatts of heat by the resonant-scattering cooler to create a tiny stream of near-lightspeed ions that are collected from a tank on the ship (or even the interstellar medium itself, as Starfish Prime's answer notes). If someone were onboard, they wouldn't be able to notice the acceleration, but it's definitely there, and if you're planning century-long missions, that's good enough.
